# Wordpress menus not displaying right format

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am doing theme integration and want to integrate static menu to dyncamic menu in wordpress.But menus displaying in wrong way.Where i am wrong ? here is my code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav cl-effect-8">
    <li>
    <?php 
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'class' => 'active' ) );?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
       <?php
             $defaults = array(
                     'theme_location'  => '',
                     'menu'            => 'menu 1',
                     'container'       => 'div',
                     'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                     'container_id'    => 'navbarCollapse',
                     'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
                     'menu_id'         => '',
                     'echo'            => true,
                     'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                     'before'          => '',
                     'after'           => '',
                     'link_before'     => '',
                     'link_after'      => '',
                     'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                     'depth'           => 0,
                     'walker'          => ''
              );

              wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

        ?>

</nav>
```